# What is an animated surface mesh?

Tags: animation, cg

I am reading the paper [Animated Mesh Approximation With Sphere-Meshes](http://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/~boubek/papers/ASM/) . The input of the algorithm mentioned in the paper is an animated surface mesh, but I do not know what an animated surface mesh is. I just learn a little about surface mesh, which may be an .off file on the disk.

[image: A snapshot from the paper.]

What is an animated surface mesh? What kind of file format do animated surface meshes have on the disk?

Answer (score 1):

I have got a good answer to this question from https://www.zhihu.com/question/50173048?from=profile_question_card.

The paper says:

> Problem statement. We aim at approximating a mesh animation
>   with F frames, (meaning F different triangles meshes having
>   the same connectivity) with an animated sphere-mesh (a mesh
>   where each vertex is associated with a time-varying sphere).

So the animated surface mesh is a mesh animation with F frames.Every frame is a mesh with same connectivity.

And the horse models in the paper can be got from here: [Deformation Transfer for Triangle Meshes -- Data](http://people.csail.mit.edu/sumner/research/deftransfer/data.html). And other models (eg: Capoeira，Samba) in the paper can be got from http[:]//people.csail.mit.edu/drdaniel/mesh_animation/.

Thanks Xia Qing again.

原作者：夏清
来源：知乎
著作权归作者所有，转载请联系作者获得授权。